VB.Net Windows Service not writing to the Application Event Log
I have a VB.net program targeting .Net 4.8 that contains a executable and two different background services.  One service, written a couple years ago, runs multiple instances based on a command line argument and the other, written a month ago, runs as a management service for cleanup tasks.  Both have some basic logging built in that goes to the standard Windows application log but one of the two will not log no matter what I do.  Both are using the same command for logging such as:
My.Application.Log.WriteEntry($"MyService for location {MyLocationID} ({MyLocationName}) is now active.")
Both are using identical app.config files based on the Microsoft documentation.  In fact I copied the working services app.config over to the non-working one and only changed the application name part but that didn't fix it.  Both have AutoLog = False as the first line after OnStart() however if I comment that line out the start and stop of the non-logging service DOES show up in the event log.  So the default autolog messages are getting through but my manual logging is not.  Both are being installed through sc.exe at the same time in the same way.
As the one service is logging correctly I'm not sure why the other wouldn't be since it's using the same app.config file.  What could I be missing?
EDIT: Couple more things I have tried:

Ran through this Microsoft Document deleting and recreating the app.config from scratch including verifying the strongly named type was correctly being referenced
Created a completely new project with a test service that does nothing other then log to the eventlog once every 30 seconds with a increasing counter.  Used the guide above to setup app.config.  Nothing within OnStart or OnStop logged but logging within my timer_elapsed sub properly logged the counter.
Both services run under local system so it's not a permissions issue and are installed using sc.exe as a admin.


After many hours of working on this and creating a separate test service just to play with without messing up the original too much I think I've found a answer.  Even though most of the documentation calls for what I'm doing:
My.Application.Log.WriteEntry("my text to log")
it simply didn't work in the second service.  So I started using a custom EventLog with my application name instead of the default Application log.  However while playing with that I found a event that still went to the default log and the rest went to my log.  Turns out this was a happy little accident, I spelled my custom event log incorrectly so it defaulted to the Application log.  Which lead me to this code:
EventLog.WriteEntry("My Applications Name", $"My message for the log.", EventLogEntryType.Enumeration)
In my app.config for the shared listener under initializeData I have my applications name that matches each EventLog write but otherwise it is using the Microsoft documentation examples for app.config.  This is now consistently working throughout both services and the main application.
